# Navigation Drawer - Have only icons and very big

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer

I have a nav drawer implemented in my activity. The audience for my app is the elderly and I want the icons to be very large and take up the whole drawer height.

[image]

I am looking to have the 4 icons evenly spaced out and to have no text just big icons. I have tried playing around with the tag:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true"></dimen>
```

but I have not been able to get it to work. The icons simply keep overlapping each other when they get too big near the top. The images always seem to be contained in the header layout.

Answer (score 3):

Create custom view and layout for drawer

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_left" />
```

nav_header_left.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/right_side_header_bg_color"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/fifty"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/twenty"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/twenty"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gall_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_add_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/media_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Gallery" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. All the icons are bunched at the top

Comment: This is my drawerlayout: <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

Comment: All the icons are squished int he header layout. It looks like all the icons are trying to fit in that header.

Comment: yes some device not showing drawer full screen
calculate & add your device height to nav_header_left.xml to root layout for full screen

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-qzh7CYvnkbWUs1cGVpRHNPNFE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for navigationView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/theme_color_dark"
            style="@style/AppTheme"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menu_fragement"
    android:tag="Menu"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.app.medcallz.fragments.MenuFragement"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MenuFragment:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/options_container"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_below="@+id/user_detail_container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationsIcon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nav_notificatios"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/account_divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/login_divider_width"
        android:background="@color/white_color"
        android:visibility="visible"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```